# JSONP забрать ответ

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp

Есть удалённый сервер (на клиентской машине), который принимает запросы только определённого формата, если указать на примере JQuery dataType:JSONP. Иначе запросы отвергаются, как кросс-браузерные.

Однако, сервер принимает следующий запрос:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://site.com:6898/server/api",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        method: "get_token",
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log("success:");console.log(response );
    }
    error: function( xhr, status, error ) {
        console.log("error:"); console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr) );

    },
 complete: function (xhr, textStatus){
            console.log( "complete: " + JSON.stringify(xhr)+" "+ textStatus);
            }
});
</script>
```

Ключевым, здесь является dataType: "jsonp". Если указать любой другой тип, запрос отвергается, как кросс-доменный, запрещённый севером.

Однако, ввиду особой спецификации JSONP, ответ (RAW тело) выглядит следующим образом:

```
{"result": {"token": "85973778790d3f951631a6406d9186b758048bbcb0e56b2f73bb5ed23720a705"}, "error": null}
```

Т.о., броузер не в состоянии обработать такой ответ, т.к. нет названия callback функции, и возвращает ошибку:
*SyntaxError: missing ; before statement*

В консоле, обработанный ответы
ERROR:
*{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}*
COMPLETE (textStatus):
*parsererror*

Всё логично. Браузер не может распарсить JSONP, т.к. формат кривой. Однако, только так сервер отвечает.

Вопрос: как всё-таки можно забрать RAW ответ (тело)?